# How to convert txt.gz into fastq.gz?

Tags: fastq

I'm a newbie to bioinfo. I'm trying to use galaxy.networkanalyst.ca for the analysis of RNA-Seq data and for that I need to convert ***txt.gz files into fastq.gz files***.

[image: PIc1]

Link: [GSM4273445](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM4273445) is one sample and the whole series is from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE143735).

I've Googled to find out if there are online tools to convert it, but there aren't any. Besides, there is no discussion addressing this format conversion on researchgate.

I intend to use this RNA-Seq data and investigate the relative expression of some specific transcripts of interest. I have been introduced to 'galaxy.networkanalyst.ca' where the very first step is to upload fastq files. In addition to this I was aware of ncbi GEOdatasets as source of open RnA-Seq data.

Can anyone suggest a method or tool for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a quick look at the file you linked to and this is a featureCounts file - this list the number of reads for each gene/transcript (COUTNS.txt in the file name pretty much gave it away that it was going to be a file of, well counts).

I can't help you with Galaxy, but if you want to do an RNA-seq analysis, the count data + metadata is likely all you'll need.

If you really want to do the preprocessing and mapping yourself, the fastq files can be downloaded from the SRA archive (SRP242087) - click on the SRA link in your whole series link.